# How to set timeout in *os.File/io.Read in golang

Tags: go, timeout

I know there is a function called `SetReadDeadline` that can set a timeout in socket(conn.net) reading, while io.Read not. There is a way that starts another routine as a timer to solve this problem, but it brings another problem that the reader routine(io.Read) still block:

```
func (self *TimeoutReader) Read(buf []byte) (n int, err error) { 
    ch := make(chan bool) 
    n = 0 
    err = nil 
    go func() { // this goroutime still exist even when timeout
            n, err = self.reader.Read(buf) 
            ch <- true 
    }() 
    select { 
    case <-ch: 
            return 
    case <-time.After(self.timeout): 
            return 0, errors.New("Timeout") 
    } 
    return 
}
```

This question is similar in this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/Hmjf5Ws8g5w/cbj6JyaCpKMJ), but the answer is unclear.
Do you guys have any good idea to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the concrete type of self.reader?

Comment: @CeriseLimón io.ReadWriteCloser/*io.File

Comment: For *os.File, [wait for Go 1.10.](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/71770).  The other option is to write some syscall code.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks, but is there any backup method to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried this recipe using `context`?  https://gist.github.com/dchapes/6c992bf3e943934462509338cd213e99

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky: that cannot cancel a blocked Read

Comment: @vinllen: in what situation do you have an `*os.File` that blocks indefinitely?

Comment: @JimB Read on a pipe can block indefinitely.

Comment: @CeriseLimón: yes, I know, I just wanted to know if this particular question could easily apply the self-pipe trick (though it's still a not a pretty solution). Regardless, usually you don't have an large number of these, and the answer is "just leave it".

Comment: @JimB Sorry for the delay response, for example, I just want close the os.File when then given times out or a given signal raises. However, I've no idea how to exit the os.File.read()

Answer (score 4):

Instead of setting a timeout directly on the `read`, you can `close` the `os.File` after a timeout. As written in https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Close

> Close closes the File, rendering it unusable for I/O. On files that support SetDeadline, any pending I/O operations will be canceled and return immediately with an error.

This should cause your `read` to fail immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake here is something different:

When you read from the reader you just read one time and that is wrong:

```
go func() { 
        n, err = self.reader.Read(buf) // this Read needs to be in a loop
        ch <- true 
}()
```

Here is a simple example (https://play.golang.org/p/2AnhrbrhLrv)

```
buf := bytes.NewBufferString("0123456789")
r := make([]byte, 3)
n, err := buf.Read(r)
fmt.Println(string(r), n, err)
// Output: 012 3 <nil>
```

The size of the given slice is used when using the io.Reader. If you would log the n variable in your code you would see, that not the whole file is read. The select statement outside of your goroutine is at the wrong place.

```
go func() {
    a := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            result <- []byte{}
            return
        default:
            _, err = self.reader.Read(buf)
            if err == io.EOF {
                result <- a
                return
            }
        }
    }
}()
```

But there is something more! You want to implement the io.Reader interface. After the `Read()` method is called until the file ends you should not start a goroutine in here, because you just read chunks of the file. 
Also the timeout inside the Read() method doesn't help, because that timeout works for each call and not for the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @apxp's point about looping over Read, you could use a buffer size of 1 byte so that you never block as long is there is data to read.

When interacting with external resources anything can happen.  It is possible for any given io.Reader implementation to simply block forever. Here, I'll write one for you...

```
type BlockingReader struct{}

func (BlockingReader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    <-make(chan struct{})
    return 0, nil
}
```

Remember anyone can implement an interface, so you can't make any assumptions that it will behave like `*os.File` or any other standard library `io.Reader`. In addition to asinine coding like mine above, an `io.Reader` could legitimately connect to a resources that can block forever.

You cannot kill gorountines, so if an io.Reader truly blocks forever the blocked goroutine will continue to consume resources until your application terminates. However, this shouldn't be a problem, a blocked goroutine does not consume much in the way of resources, and should be fine as long as you don't blindly retry blocked Reads by spawning more gorountines.

Comment: Performance is greatly sacrificed with 1 byte reads, not ideal in the general case.