# How to close golang os.File when it is blocking in reading?

Tags: go, goroutine

I start two goroutines to forward message between two `io.ReadWriter` where `rw1` is a TCP connection with type `Conn.net` and `rw2` is the type of `*os.File` which use `pty` [library](https://github.com/kr/pty) to build telnet connection. Here comes the forwarding code:

```
func Connection(northConn net.Conn) {
    // code omit ...        

    transport(northConn, sourthConn)

    // code omit ...

    sourthConn.Close() // close
}

func transport(rw1, rw2 io.ReadWriter) error {
    errc := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        _, err := io.Copy(rw1, rw2)
        errc <- err
    }()

    go func() {
        _, err := io.Copy(rw2, rw1)
        errc <- err
    }()

    err := <-errc
    if err != nil && err == io.EOF {
        err = nil
    }
    return err
}
```

The pipeline is "`A`<->`rw1(northConn)`<->`rw2(sourthConn)`<->`telnet server`" where A communicate with rw1 through TCP connection, `rw2` communicate with telnet server through `*os.File` read and write. The above two goroutines just forwarding message between `rw1` and `rw2`.
These two goroutines can be normally closed if sending `exit` command from `A` so that connection between `rw2` and `telnet server` close firstly and `A`<->`rw1` close secondly. But if I shutdown the A terminal which means sending `EOF` to `rw1` only, the `A`<->`rw1` connection can be closed while `rw2`<->`telnet server` not. The second goroutine can exit normally while the first goroutine is still blocking at `io.Copy(rw1, rw2)`. And the `sourthConn.Close()` is blocking too.
So my question is how to make the first goroutine exit in this situation and the `sourth.Close()` run unblocking? I came up with an idea that send `exit` command in the second goroutine after `rw1` receive `EOF` but I don't know whether this is a good method and whether this may bring bugs:

```
go func() {
    _, err := io.Copy(rw2, rw1)
    rw2.Write([]byte("exit\n")) // add this sentence
    errc <- err
}()
```

How can I shutdown the `*os.File` directly from outside?

Comment: I don't quite understand why closing `A<->rw1` can't be used to terminate the whole chain. I'd modify the code in all the "piping" goroutines in such a way that when `io.Copy` in them returns `io.EOF`, they close their other end of the pipe as well so that EOF gets propagated across all the pipeline.

Comment: @kostix hi, Kostix, Thanks for your reply. In my understanding, there are two goroutines that serve for the different direction. If `A<->rw1` is closed, the second goroutine will exit because `rw1` receive `EOF` but the first will not because `rw2` doesn't receive `EOF`. If the `sourthConn.Close()` isn't blocking, the first goroutine can exit because the `rw2(sourthConn)` is closed. But the problem is the `sourthConn.Close()` is blocking when `sourthConn.read()` calls which is my guess.

Comment: As commented in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586404/how-to-set-timeout-in-os-file-io-read-in-golang), you cannot timeout (yet) or close a blocked Read on an `*os.File`.  Why are you building a telnet connection through an `*os.File`, and not a network connection?

Comment: @JimB It is because I find a [pty library](https://github.com/kr/pty) in GitHub which use `*os.File` to start `os.exec.Command`. Do you have any other way to start `telnet` connection?

Comment: Does something like https://godoc.org/github.com/ziutek/telnet suit your needs? Also, if you're reading the output from an `exec.Cmd`, then the pipe will be closed when the process terminates and the `Read` will return, so I'm still not understanding where you need to interrupt a `Read` call.